in mongodb how do i save the last instance of archive entities
I have a a stream of entity transactions. Each transaction is a json consists of "_id" of the entity and a time of the transaction (there are many more fields). I want to save in the last transaction of each entity in my mongodb collection.
meaning i want to replace an existing mongo record if it has the same "_id" and the new time is greater the the current time. If the "_id" does not exists yet, then I want to insert it as a new record.
Currently I have a semi working version. I just do 2 queries. If I am processing 100 transaction than first I query the mongo to get all the "_id"s and their time field currently in my collection than I just filter it in my python project than I create replace one statements for all the new records and the records with a newer time field and I do a bulk_write operation.
However there is a problem when there are few workers at the same time. what if 2 workers try to process the same entity "_id" at the same time. The data might be wrong.
As we are using kafka for the data stream we thought maybe just put a key to the kafka messages so all the transactions with the same "_id" will go to the same worker, however, it is also not possible cause it limits our scalability.
So I came up with a new solution to save all the data as an archive data in my mongo collection. For each json I will convert it to look like {"_id":uuid, "schema":{original_transaction}}. And I will build a cron job that will run every 5 min and delete old record.
Yet maybe there is just an easy solution I am missing so I would like to know if there is a better and easier solution

Have you considered using find_one_and_replace or find_one_and_update with upsert=True?

You can try something like this, for each entity JSON (json) input: db.collection.updateOne(   { _id: json._id,  tx_time: { $lt: json.tx_time } },   { $set: { _id: json._id, tx_time: json.tx_time, other: json.other_fld } },   { upsert: true } ). Note this might throw E11000 Duplicate Key Error, which you can catch. This is MongoDB shell syntax (not Python).

Some thoughts. (option a) You can also think about processing the json entity stream and getting the latest transaction time for an entity _id and use it to update the database collection. (option b) You can possibly store these entity stream to a database collection and aggregate it to get the latest transaction for each entity _id.  There is a possibility to use aggregation $merge stage, in this case.

@rickhg12hs I dont see any benefit of find_one_and_replace over just replace_one statement. as I dont actually need to get the result.

@prasad_ about ur second answer, as I stated I can't currently aggregate based on the time as it is running on multiple pods. The merge option is pretty similar to the second solution I stated. Ur first answer is interesting. I can indeed use bulk_write of replace_one operations with the upsert key. After reading more i also need to state the key ordered=False so the bulk_write won't fail for each duplicate key error. Moreover, the exception should get is BulkWriteError which should contain all the details the errors that occurred.

Another solution i came up with is using transactions. From what i read in the documentation and other places online the transaction should lock all the documents i read or write to during the transaction so it will introduce order and therefore, will eliminate my concurrency issues

Using MongoDB transactions requires that your deployment is a replica-set.
